# How I can verify my PL/SQL syntax

Tags: compiler-construction, plsql

Sorry my English is bad. I hope you can get what I want.

I have lots of *.sql files that I want to write a program to compile them and inform me if there is any issues (problems or mistakes).

One of my friends writes an IDE for java, as I remember he use javac to generate the error codes.  On the other hand I've seen the IDEs Visual Studio or Netbean tell you automatically if there are errors.  So now I want to know any one has any idea how you can do that with sql files?

In other words I want to write an Editor for SQL files(PL/SQL) that compile my code and tell me what is my error.

This problem raise up when I try to compile all of them in SQL PLUS, it's so boring.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL*Plus can be run on the command line.  Therefore you can use it in a manner similar to your friend's use of javac.

```
> sqlplus username/password@connection_identifier @scriptToExecute.sql
```

Remember that your actions can have consequences, so you will want to implement rollback for sql and perhaps temporary naming for ddl/dml commands.

Or alternatively, download Oracle's free [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) tool that already does all that.

Answer (score 5):

A .sql file could contain many different things - DDL, SQL queries, DML, PL/SQL anonymous blocks, as well as `CREATE` commands for views and stored procedures/functions/packages.

You need to know what are in those .sql files. If you just run them blindly in SQL*Plus, you don't know what they might do - I could give you the set of .sql scripts in my home folder, and you'd find that your database would be in a pretty bad state if you just ran them randomly - some scripts create/modify/drop tables, or delete or modify data, some scripts COMMIT their changes (so issuing a ROLLBACK after running the script won't help you), other scripts start or stop the database :)

If you know that all your .sql scripts contain nothing but `CREATE` commands for views or stored procedures, function and/or packages, you can just run them all from the SQL*Plus command line - you can generate a script quite easily that runs them all one after each other - then check the `USER_OBJECTS`/`ALL_OBJECTS`/`DBA_OBJECTS` for anything where `STATUS = 'INVALID'` and query `USER_ERRORS` for any compiler errors. Remember, however, even **this approach is destructive** because it will overwrite any existing stored procedures etc. that were in the database you run them in.

Comment: ;)) Thanks,I know. actually recently I attend to a Configuration team that they update their software at end of week,so,we need just compile the all scripts that other developer and customer use the new source...
the last manager make a batch file that put all the sql code like this:
sta "x:\xxx\sss\kkk.sql"
sta "xx:\xxx\sss\dddd.sql"
sta "x:\xxx\sss\kss.sql"
sta "xx:\xxx\sss\mmmdd.sql"
...

between run this sql file we recieve error,he put "/" some times and error will solved but i think this work is so boring.in this case i wana try to write a program do this for me.
any command?

Comment: @rima, is that another question? "/" *is* the command to execute a PL/SQL block in SQL*Plus. Testing may be boring but that's part of the job :)