# Sending second command to cmd after first command ends

Tags: c#, cmd

enter code hereI want to send a command to cmd after the first command I sent will end. When I'm trying to call another command by `BeginErrorReadLine()` there is an error: "An async operation already started on the stream".

How can I connect the process again and send another command? (I want to send the second command by pressing another button).

First command with cmd process:

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
cmdStartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
cmdStartInfo.Arguments = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ttk"] + commandline;
cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmdStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

_cmd = new Process();
_cmd.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;


if (_cmd.Start())
{
    _cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
    _cmd.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_ErrorDataReceived);
    _cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);

    _cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();


}
else
{
    _cmd = null;
}
```

Comment: btw System.Net can send ICMP pings ...

Comment: This is ugly. In your case there's no need for .NET, you could achieve everything with a simple batch script.

Comment: @Robert the ping is only an example. actually i'm using a python script ant i want to send to this script a command at the end of the first. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `Process` has an `Exited` event to achieve this. In your case, it would then be:

```
// non-blocking
_cmd.Exited += (sender, eventArgs) => { /* run after process exists */ };
```

or, if blocking is ok, you just go like this:

```
_cmd.Start();
_cmd.WaitForExit(); // Blocking (until _cmd exists)
```

Comment: How do I do this with in new button?

Comment: But i don't know what to write in this handler. How can I refer to the script again, after it finished, and run a new command. (I dont want to close the process, just to connect it again). Thanks!!

Comment: You mean something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851402/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-c-sharp

Comment: I need to call the second command with a click on button2. However my process is asynchronous.  How can I refer again to this proccess by button click and send another command?